# Is a monoid a magma?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid, magma

According to [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid), a monoid is defined as an object that contains

1. An associative binary operation
2. An identity element

There is no mention of the object necessarily containing a set.

The same page includes the statement "a monoid is a semigroup with an identity element". It is my understanding that a semigroup is a magma with additional constraints, is this correct?

The page also compares a monoid and a magma, stating a monoid simply has more constraints. But doesn't a monoid lack magma's constraint of having to contain a set?

So does this mean a monoid does necessitate a set? Or have I misunderstood something?

I might just be nitpicking the specific wording of a wikipedia page, but I don't want to assume it's an error before I understand it for sure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the definition section of the article as opposed to the definition given in the introduction paragraph?

Comment: Monoids, magmas, semigroups, groups, etc. all are supposed to be sets in the first place (or contain sets, if you mean the word "contain" in the sense of "a set is part of their specification").

Comment: How no? *"Suppose that S is a set and • is some binary operation..."*

Comment: It says that a monoid is an algebraic structure, which on its turn is a **set** with one or more finitary operations. Yes a monoid can be looked at as a magma with special properties.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the [magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)#Types_of_magmas) wikipedia page, there is the following diagram:

> [image]

So, yes. A monoid is a magma with associativity and identity which is also a semigroup with identity. Both the magma and monoid have an attached set, look both pages and see the definitions.

Answer (score 3):

An *algebraic structure* is an object of the form $(S, f_1,\dots,f_k)$ where $f_1,\dots,f_k$ are operations on $S$, that is, they are functions $f_i\colon S^{r_i}\to S$, and $r_i$ is called the arity of the function $f_i$. A $0$-ary function is understood as a constant symbol. It is often required that $S$ be a nonempty set, but this is in many cases only a matter of convention.

So, a monoid is a structure $(S,f,id)$ where $f\colon S^2\to S$ and $id$ is $0$-ary (it is called the *identity element* in this context. Moreover we require that $f$ and $id$ satisfy $f(id,x)=x$ and $f(f(x,y),z)= f(x,f(y,z))$.

A magma is a structure $(S,f)$ with no additional restriction except that $f$ is $2$-ary. So even if properly speaking a monoid *is not* a magma, if you forget that the monoid has an identity element it becomes a magma (we call this "forgetting" operation a *reduct* in model theory).

Similarly, a semigroup is a structure $(S,f)$ where $f$ again needs to be associative. No identity element here, but every monoid can be understood as a semigroup by forgetting the identity element.

Comment: What does n-ary mean?

Comment: A function $f\colon S^n\to S$ is said to have *arity $n$*, or we say that it is $n$-ary.

Comment: Thank you, this also clarifies the term "finitary", which means the function takes a finite number of arguments